# Batch rename files with multiple extensions

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, rename

This has been driving me crazy for quite a while.

I have files with multiple useless extensions in the filename.

For example, batch-converting from MP4 to MP3 via command-line:-

---

```
cd /d "%1"
for /r %%x in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%x" -ar 24000 "%%x.wav"
for /r %%x in ("*.wav") do lame "%%x" "%%x.mp3" -m m -s 24k -b 96k
del *.wav
```

---

This takes the file "input.mp4" and creates "input.mp4.wav.mp3" instead of "input.mp3".

I would really like to be able to batch-rename all files with these problematic filenames, *instead* of a solution that resolves it during the conversion process.  The reason being is that I've already done a lot of converting so far.  I've tried a lot of different techniques in the BAT file, and I really need a solution that will work in CMD, not Powershell or some other third-party software.  A very small freeware EXE might be acceptable, though.

Thanks.
.
.
.

Comment: why are you opposed to using the REPLACEMENT for bat/cmd scripting?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - I'm not opposed to alternatives, but they need to be standalone command-line solutions that also work from a BAT file, such as FFMPEG and LAME.

Comment: you can run virtually any exe from PoSh just like you can with cmd/bat scripts. try searching for `powershell ffmpeg` to see some examples. ///// plus, the way PoSh handles loops is easier to understand and to tinker with. take a look at `Get-Help about_Foreach` and `Get-Help about_Foreach -Examples` ... or do a search for `powershell loop`.

Comment: I already said I can't use it, that everything needs to be command-line and using standalone distributable utilities.  Please don't attempt to 'move the goalposts' if you are unable to help, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I found this nice little utility which gave me a lot of hope, but so far I haven't had any luck even with this:- https://github.com/ChuckDaniels87/rnr/releases/tag/v0.3.0

Comment: my request was for the WHY of it ... party out of curiosity, but also because your post seems like a classic X, Y situation. your comment `everything needs to be command-line` would certainly SEEM to include the _current windows command line_ ... which is _powershell_. [*grin*]

Comment: I know it's not what you asked for, but the reason for the multiple extensions is `"%%x.mp3"`, which just adds `.mp3` to the full original filename including its extension(s). The pure filename without path or (the last) extension is `%%~nx`, drive/path/filename without extension is `%%~dpnx`. So replacing `%%x.mp3` with either (depending on your needs) with `%%~nx.mp3` or `%%~dpnx.mp3` avoids your problem in the future. (Same goes for the `.wav` line, of course). (See `for /?` to learn more about those modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution with rnr.exe:-

```
rnr -f -r mp4.wav.mp3 mp3 .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the extension, use "~" syntax; see `for/?` for details.

In your case you must use "~n" which returns the name without the extension of the loop variable "%%x".
If you want to add drive letter and path also, you must combine dpn like `%%~dpnx%`.

So the corrected batch wold be:

```
cd /d "%1"
for /r %%x in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%x" -ar 24000 "%%~dpnx.wav"
for /r %%x in ("*.wav") do lame "%%x" "%%~dpnx.mp3" -m m -s 24k -b 96k
del *.wav
```

HTH
Thomas